# OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyduino-0.0.0-py2.7.egg'

Tags: python, installation, setup.py, pypi

I am trying to install and uninstall a package.I have written a setup.py script.While installing the script works fine and the package installs.But while uninstalling package uninstalls but throw some errors.I am using pip uninstall package_name for uninstalling.Here is the traceback

```
Uninstalling pyduino-0.0.0:
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyduino-0.0.0-py2.7.egg
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled pyduino-0.0.0
The directory '/home/billy/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 221, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 252, in main
    pip_version_check(session)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/outdated.py", line 102, in pip_version_check
    installed_version = get_installed_version("pip")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 848, in get_installed_version
    working_set = pkg_resources.WorkingSet()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 619, in __init__
    self.add_entry(entry)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 675, in add_entry
    for dist in find_distributions(entry, True):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1942, in find_eggs_in_zip
    if metadata.has_metadata('PKG-INFO'):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1463, in has_metadata
    return self.egg_info and self._has(self._fn(self.egg_info, name))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1824, in _has
    return zip_path in self.zipinfo or zip_path in self._index()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1704, in zipinfo
    return self._zip_manifests.load(self.loader.archive)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1644, in load
    mtime = os.stat(path).st_mtime
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyduino-0.0.0-py2.7.egg'
```

Meanwhile package uninstalls.When i tried the command pip freeze package does not show up.So,why does the above errors show up?Thanks in advance for helping...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.I didn't upgrade pip after installing.Later,I upgraded and works perfectly..